Measure real corona discharge intensity, range 2000-7500V?
I need to measure the actual corona discharge intensity produced by a particular circuit and electrode array.  I'd love numbers as hard as possible, though am not sure what units apply; alternatively, a qualitative number relative to that produced by an available test standard will do.  The standard takes in 0.05A at 12VDC and outputs discharge at 5000V; the new circuit is variable, max being 1AM in and 11kV discharge, but I won't be using higher than 7500V.
Thus far research seems to indicate that appropriate UV detection may be the lowest-hanging-fruit method, but I haven't found hard data as to wavelengths and sensitivity needed.  Anyone have a solid direction to go?  This is a low-budget project, I do not have institutional resources to use at this time.
